# Mgo insert command not creating db or inserting document

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

My goal is to implement this [code](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1). Except instead of using sql I want to use mongoDB. I think there is an issue with how I handle my sessions.

I'm trying to use mgo to insert some user data into MongoDB via a Rest API. Whenever I open the mongo shell and run the `show dbs` command, the `poll` DB is not displayed. I'm using Postman to test the Rest API. Any ideas what am I might be doing wrong in the insertion process? I tried creating the collection first in the mongo shell and then running the `CreateUser` function but I still didnt see the `poll` DB get created.

**User**

```
type User struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string  `json:"password"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}
```

**UserDAO**

```
type UserDAO struct {
    session *mgo.Session
}
```

**Creating a session**

```
func GetMongoSession() *mgo.Session {
    if mgoSession == nil {
        var err error
        mgoSession, err = mgo.Dial("localhost")
        mgoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Failed to start the Mongo session.")
        }
    }
    return mgoSession.Clone()
}
```

I pass a User struct into the `CreateUser` function that I create using Postman:

```
{
    "username":"uname",
    "password":"pass",
    "email":"test@mail.com"
}
```

Then I just respond with the same struct and receive this output:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "username": "uname",
    "password": "pass",
    "email": "test@mail.com"
}
```

**Creating a user**

```
func (dao *UserDAO) CreateUser(u *User) (*User, error) {
    //return errors.New("Not implemented")

    // Get "users" collection

    dao.session = GetMongoSession()

    c := dao.session.DB("poll").C("user")

    defer dao.session.Close()

    //u.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
    err :=  c.Insert(u)

    if err != nil { 
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

**Http handler function**

```
func (h *Handler) CreateUserReq(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // create new user using information from the Request object
    var user User
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    if err := decoder.Decode(&user); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer r.Body.Close()

    // Create new User
    u, err := h.UserService.CreateUser(&user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(*u)
}
```

**Output of show dbs**

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

Comment: first of all your getting pointer to user struct so u need to pass the address to to u struct like this in `&u` in your function of insert

Comment: I'm passing in a pointer to a user, CreateUser(u *User), so isn't the u that gets passing into c.Insert(u)  already the address of the object?

Comment: where is `dao *UserDAO` defined in your code

Answer (score 2):

Since, I don't have full context of your application so can't diagnose what exactly issue is with your code. But I came up with close example, which is working as expected.

Please see code below.

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type User struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string        `json:"username"`
    Password string        `json:"password"`
    Email    string        `json:"email"`
}

func GetMongoSession() *mgo.Session {

    mgoSession, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    mgoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to start the Mongo session.")
    }

    return mgoSession.Clone()
}

func CreateUser(u *User) (*User, error) {

    session := GetMongoSession()

    c := session.DB("poll").C("user")
    defer session.Close()

    err := c.Insert(u)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}

func main() {

    var user = User{
        Email:    "abc@somewhere.come",
        Password: "My-secret",
        Username: "YouGuess",
    }

    _, e := CreateUser(&user)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    log.Println("Done...")
}
```

once you execute it, you should see a document in MongoDB provided that you successfully establish connection with proper credentials.

I can see following document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a80941de0a0f75123aeb435"),
    "username": "YouGuess",
    "password": "My-secret",
    "email": "abc@somewhere.come"
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness, I was trying not to make the post too long which might make things more complicated. What I'm doing in my code is implementing the architecture found here: https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1. The difference in mine would be instead of using the sql driver, I would use mgo. In the postgres.go file, I would use session *mgo.Session instesad of DB *sql.DB.

Comment: This ended up working for me after removing the DB I had created through the mongo shell and rerunning my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and first of all I check is my user struct contains data coming from postman and then there is one error also  when you are assigning the session `*mgo.Session` to non-pointer `dao.session` variable. So I have changed many a things and it is working fine creating both database with `poll` name and creating a user collection with new document also I have removed ObjectId from User struct. Check it out

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "log"
    // "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

var (
    mgoSession     *mgo.Session
)

type UserDAO struct{
    session   *mgo.Session
}

type User struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string  `json:"password"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

func GetMongoSession() *mgo.Session {
    if mgoSession == nil {
        var err error
        mgoSession, err = mgo.Dial("localhost")
        mgoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Failed to start the Mongo session.")
        }
    }
    return mgoSession.Clone()
}

func (dao *UserDAO) CreateUser(u *User) (*User, error) {
    //return errors.New("Not implemented")

    // Get "users" collection

    session := GetMongoSession()
    // log.Println(session)

    c := session.DB("poll").C("user")

    defer session.Close()

    //u.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
    err :=  c.Insert(u)

    if err != nil { 
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}

func main(){
    // this data will come from postman in your case
    jsonStr := []byte(`{
            "username":"uname",
            "password":"pass",
            "email":"test@mail.com"
        }
    `)

    var user User
    err  := json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &user)
    if err != nil{
        log.Println(err)
    }

    var dao *UserDAO

    dao.CreateUser(&user)
}
```

My collection output is:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a80993f32fcc2489f995aaf"),
    "username" : "uname",
    "password" : "pass",
    "email" : "test@mail.com"
}
```

you don't need to create a Object id for new document it will be created itself when inserting a new document. Also If you wants top just create a collection using golang and then insert data you can create it explicitly. Go through this function [create collection](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Create)

Comment: I figured an Object Id would be created on insertion but was not sure, thanks for clarifying. I created the "poll" db and the "user" collection. I then ran my Postman request to create the user and did a db.user.find() in the mongo shell. There was no output though so I dont think the insert worked.

Comment: I updated the code in the original question to include my UserDAO struct. `dao.session` is of type `*User` so that should be ok. The link I posted is essentially what my code is trying to do.

Comment: I have tried yor code but it panics every time I assign session to your dao struct session variable in this line `dao.session = GetMongoSession()`. you can try above code it is working fine. I have tested it completely